# Retrieving an array of dictionaries from UserDefaults

Tags: swift, dictionary, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to retrieve an array of dictionaries stored in UserDefaults but I can't figure our how best to do so.

Here is what I have so far:

```
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
var userWorkouts: [Dictionary<String,String>] = []
userWorkouts = userDefaults.object(forKey: "SavedDict") as? [Dictionary<String,String>]
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I get the following error: "Value of optional type '[Dictionary<String, String>]?' must be unwrapped to a value of type '[Dictionary<String, String>]'"

Comment: What do you want to happen if there is no value associated with that key in user defaults?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've declared `userWorkouts` as a non-optional variable. But the expression `userDefaults.object(forKey: "SavedDict") as? [Dictionary<String,String>]` returns an optional array, hence the error message.

You can change this to:

```
userWorkouts = userDefaults.object(forKey: "SavedDict") as? [Dictionary<String,String>] ?? []
```

Or reduce your three lines to just:

```
var userWorkouts = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "SavedDict") as? [Dictionary<String,String>] ?? []
```